# how to use variable value in LINQ to entity

Tags: linq, entity-framework

Here is my code

```
if (Count < LeaveTypeCount)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < LeaveTypeCount; i++)
    {
        var LeaveId = from l in CompObj.LeaveTypes
                      select l.LeaveID;
       var leaveIdArray = LeaveId.ToArray ();

        var LeaveDefault = (from c in CompObj.LeaveTypes
                            where (c.LeaveID ==leaveIdArray[i])
                            select new { c.DefaultLeave }).FirstOrDefault();

        Int32 DefaultCount = Convert.ToInt32(LeaveDefault.DefaultLeave);


        AssignedLeave AddObj = new AssignedLeave();
        AddObj.EmpID = EmpID;
        AddObj.AssignedYear = LeaveYear;
        AddObj.LeaveID =leaveIdArray[i];
        AddObj.TotalLeave = DefaultCount;
        CompObj.AssignedLeaves.AddObject(AddObj);
        CompObj.SaveChanges();

    }
}
```

but its showing error   **The LINQ expression node type 'ArrayIndex' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.**

How can i resolve this issue or what is the another way to do this task

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to copy the value to a local variable:

```
   var leaveIdValue = leaveIdArray[i];

    var LeaveDefault = (from c in CompObj.LeaveTypes
                        where (c.LeaveID ==leaveIdValue)
                        select new { c.DefaultLeave }).FirstOrDefault();
```

BTW, you should probably move `leaveIdArray` out of the loop, since it doesn't depend on the value of `i`.